# DHTMLX Gantt in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, dom

I'm implementing [DHTMLX Gantt Chart](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/) in LWC. I'm trying to call an LWC method from the gantt library function but it is not working.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-task-data" onclick={openModal}/>
    <div class="thegantt" lwc:dom="manual" style='width:100%;'></div>
</template>

this.isModalOpen = false;

renderedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, DHTMLX7 + '/codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js'),
            loadStyle(this, DHTMLX7 + '/codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css')
    ]).then(() => {
        const root = this.template.querySelector('.thegantt');
        root.style.height = "300px";
        const gantt = window.Gantt.getGanttInstance();

        //This method is called when a user double clicks on a task bar of the chart
        gantt.attachEvent("onTaskDblClick", function(id, e) {
            /* As per LWC's documentation, this doesn't work
            let taskInput = document.getElementById("hidden-task-data");
            taskInput.value = e;
            taskInput.click();
            */
            this.openModal(); //This doesn't work
            return true;
        });
    });
}

openModal() {
    this.isModalOpen = true;
    console.log(this.isModalOpen);
}
```

The `openModal` method is not called because `this` is not a valid reference in the gantt library. I have tried `document.getElementById` which is not working either. What are the ways I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to use `this` in a `callback function` the context changes and you loose reference to the class instance, [read here](https://javascript.info/bind)

The old solution is to store a reference to `this`(Class instance) in a separate variable (`self` in the example) and use it in the callback

The modern solution is to use [Arrow function](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions) which does not have its own `this` context and refers to the class context

```
renderedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, DHTMLX7 + '/codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js'),
            loadStyle(this, DHTMLX7 + '/codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css')
    ]).then(() => {
        const gantt = window.Gantt.getGanttInstance();

        // Using Arrow function
        gantt.attachEvent("onTaskDblClick", (id, e) => {
            this.openModal();
        });

        // Storing reference of this in another variable
        const self = this;
        gantt.attachEvent("onTaskDblClick", function(id, e) {
            self.openModal();
        });
    });
}
```